# "error_description": "The authorization code was not found or was already used" Shopify

Tags: shopify, koa, shopify-app

I am not able to get permanent access token using code.

Docs - https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth#get-a-permanent-access-token

API - POST https://holofystore.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token
Body -

{
"client_id": "abcd",
"client_secret": "shpss_token",
"code": "abcd"
}

I have created the NodeJS app using this docs - https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create

following this doc to get auth token - https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth

Posted Same Question on Shopify Community but no luck  - https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/quot-error-description-quot-quot-the-authorization-code-was-not/m-p/1338591#M67633

Comment: bro is this issue fixed. I have same issue like this. Can you give any hint on it

Comment: no luck here as-well on shopify forms

Comment: @Cyclon3 i got it. we can create an offline token by disable const USE_ONLINE_TOKENS = false; and on call back api  const redirectUrl = await Shopify.Auth.beginAuth(
      req,
      res,
      req.query.shop,
      "/auth/callback",
      false
    );

Comment: like this i fixed my issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72372129/oauth-error-invalid-request-the-authorization-code-was-not-found-or-was-already